# Are Node devDependencies included as part of a release if they are nested within dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies

Let's say I have Project A with:

```
  "dependencies": {
       "someDependency": "1.0"
   }
```

and someDependency with:

```
  "devDependencies": {
       "notwantedinproduction": "1.0"
   }
```

Will Project A included the "notwantedinproduction" dependency as part of a release build, by virtue of having it nested within dependencies a la "someDependency"?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

No, when you `npm i` it will only install the dependencies defined in that module and will not install that modules devDependencies. An easy was to see this in action is to start a new project then install express (or anything else). Express has a dev dependency for eslint but if you check your node modules you won't find eslint in there.

Comment: is there a way to force install devDependencies of dependencies ? for example on one layer recurcivelly?

Comment: @alexanne - no you cannot do that and probably don't want to. You're dev dependencies are going to be different than those you dependencies use. Instead, I would simply include the dev dependencies you wished to include in your own dev dependencies and install like normal